# How to hold data when page is reloading in jsp struts2

Tags: database, list, jsp, struts2, hashmap

I have loading data from database for `ArrayList`. Then I use that data for updating process. I am search and Load data to `ArrayList`. This is the code for load data when searching.

```
System.out.println("In search job method");

    region ="TEST";
    PcinitialdataEjb pcinEjb=new PcinitialdataEjb(region);
    pcinitiladataList = new ArrayList<Pcinitialdata>();

    System.out.println(hiddentableRadioButtonValue+"**************************************************************************");

    if(idSearchType.equalsIgnoreCase("comRef"))
    {
        pcinitiladataList=pcinEjb.getDataForEstNumber("510.00/EBS/12/0031","Commercial");
        System.out.println(idSearchType);
    }
    else if(idSearchType.equalsIgnoreCase("constructRef"))
    {

        pcinitiladataList=pcinEjb.getDataForEstNumber("510.00/EBS/12/0031","customerRef");
    }
    else if(idSearchType.equalsIgnoreCase("projJobNo"))
    {

        pcinitiladataList=pcinEjb.getDataForEstNumber("510.00/EBS/12/0031","projNoJobNo");
    }


    Pcinitialdata aa=new Pcinitialdata();
    aa.setDecrp("doorwerfxcv");
    pcinitiladataList.add(aa);
    System.out.println(pcinitiladataList.toString());
    for(int i = 0; i < pcinitiladataList.size(); i++) {   

        if(i==0)
        System.out.print(pcinitiladataList.get(i));


        if(i==1)
        System.out.print((String)pcinitiladataList.get(i).getDecrp());
    }
```

This code works perfectly. My problem is after i load data to jsp table then i use radio button to select the raw. Then i click load button to load data to interface. But my problem is when i click load button, pcinitialdata list is became null. 
This is the code for load button click.

```
public String loadValuesForPage()
{
    if(pcinitiladataList.equals(null))
    {

        String resrult=searchJob();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < pcinitiladataList.size(); i++) {   
        if((hiddentableRadioButtonValue.equalsIgnoreCase(pcinitiladataList.get(i).getEstNo())))
        {

            Pcinitialdata estNoObject=new Pcinitialdata();
            estNoObject=pcinitiladataList.get(i);

            fileNo=estNoObject.getEstNo();
        }
    }


    return SUCCESS;
}
```

How can i hold data until i finish my update process??

When i click update button, My arrayList became null. Is there any way to hold that data until I finish my update process. Can i use Hoshmap to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! Store your data into session, and after updation completed remove your data from session.

In this example i am storing a arraylist with name `myarrayList`   into my session with key name  `holdarrylist`

```
 if ( !session.containsKey(holdarrylist) ) 
{
// Place the arraylist into the session  eg. myarrayList  
session.put(myarrayList, holdarrylist); //myarrayList is your arraylist ato be kept in the session with the name  holdarrylist 
} else {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>) session.get("holdarrylist");
     list.add( 1 /* Do here what ever you want */);
// Retrieve session data

    --------------
    //--do your updation work----
    //after remove the arraylist from session  
    //session.remove("holdarrylist");
 }
```

Comment: if you think your problem is solved by my answer . Please consider accepting my answer

Comment: what is my arrayllist and hodkarraaylist. i have only one arraylist. i have only one arraylist. But i have values in my session. This is the way i tried.
'if(!session.containsKey(pcinitiladataList))
  {
   session.put(getSessionKey("userName"),pcinitiladataList);
  }
List<Pcinitialdata> pcinitiladataListjj;
  pcinitiladataListjj=(List<Pcinitialdata>)session.get(pcinitiladataList);
  
'

Comment: what is my arrayllist and hodkarraaylist. i have only one arraylist. i have only one arraylist. But i have values in my session. This is the way i tried.
`if(!session.containsKey(pcinitiladataList))
  {
   session.put(getSessionKey("userName"),pcinitiladataList);
  }
List<Pcinitialdata> pcinitiladataListjj;
  pcinitiladataListjj=(List<Pcinitialdata>)session.get(pcinitiladataList); 
'
But this is giving an error.. Nulpointer exception